# How do I move an embedded manifest to external .manifest file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, manifest

I have an existing C# application that has a manifest file which is embedded into the exe. How do I change this to use an external manifest that will be included in the setup.msi?

I can only see options (in the Project Properties) to create the application without a manifest, or to embed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution explorer, try changing the Build Action for the manifest to Content.

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track. I did have to change the name of the manifest from app.manifest to have the same root name as my exe and also manually include it in the setup project.

Comment: This works for me too, but somehow xml manifest is still integrated inside the main .exe file and it's not OK (in my opinion).
I'm not sure what is the priority for manifest fetching, even if I specified my default manifest as external file (in project settings/.csproj file). Who knows which one is considered first: internal one or external.
P.S. I will check it and will post a new answer later.

Answer (score 3):

Use the MT utility (part of Visual Studio) to manipulate manifest files.

From the online help:

```
> To extract manifest out of a dll:
mt.exe -inputresource:dll_with_manifest.dll;#1 -out:extracted.manifest
```

Comment: This utility is used to extract a manifest from a pre-compiled dll or exe. I already have the manifest as part of my project, but I want to know how I can change the project so that it is not embedded, but rather included in the setup as a separate file and also copied to the bin/debug directory when compiling and debugging